# Что означает $$ в PHP?

Tags: php

Что означает `$$` перед именем переменной в PHP?

Comment: я в начале подумал, что это как в перл или bash'e просто получение текущего pid процесса. Но в пхп оно не работает.

А  так это называется [переменная переменная](http://www.php.su/learnphp/vars/?varsvars).

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Думаю из этого примера станет все понятно:

```
$foo = 'bar';
$bar = 'I am text';
echo $$foo; // I am text
```

Просто представьте, что в выражении `$$foo` вместо `$foo` будет подставлено его значение и получится `$bar`.
Можно кстати не ограничиваться этим и писать что-нибудь подобное:

```
$$$$$$$$$foo
```

[Документация по вопросу](http://php.net/manual/ru/language.variables.variable.php)

Comment: "Можно кстати не ограничиваться этим" - [вот отличная штука](http://govnokod.ru/17415)