Значение двойного знака $ в контексте статьи
Есть статья из документации к Битрикс - Настройка ЧПУ, в которой сказано

Но жесткая проверка в preg_match не позволит сделать ссылки вида www.myserver.ru/users/user_login/?r1=banner&r2=com­puterra.ru, которые очень необходимы для анализа рекламных компаний. Поэтому, в начале файла 404.php пишем:

<?$arURI = parse_url($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]);
$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] = $arURI["path"];
if(!empty($arURI["query"]))
{
parse_str($arURI["query"],$par);
foreach($par as $key => $val)
{
global $$key;
$$key = $val;
}
}
?>

Возник вопрос: "Зачем используется двойной знак $ в
global $$key;
$$key = $val;

вместо одинарного?"
Почему именно в данной статье используется двойной $? Просто такое ощущение, что значения GET параметров будут записаны в $val.
Я новичок (джун), поэтому прошу не минусовать.

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/289885/%D0%A7%D1%82%D0%BE-%D0%BE%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%B2-php

Имя переменной хранится в переменной. Вызов $foo = 'foo value'; $bar = 'foo'; echo $$bar; //foo value, равносилен вызову $foo = 'foo value'; echo $foo; //foo value

А можете объяснить почему в контексте статьи используется двойной $?

Потому что её автор - идиот. Он никогда не слышал про массивы, и вместо того чтобы нормально обращаться к полученным данным как к элементам массива $par (например $par['r1'] и $par['r2']), он пытается получить глобальные переменные $r1 и $r2. Но учитывая, что имена берутся из адреса, в котором можно написать что угодно, это значит что этот код позволит любому школьнику перезаписать любую переменную в коде, создавая дыру в безопасности размером с Титаник. А к настройке ЧПУ эти $$ не имеют никакого отношения.
